# Laravel 4 not found error after changing view of folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

In order to organize better my views and controllers, i changed a view file to another folder and changed the respective controllers and methods name. Everything was working fine, but now it doesn't find the route or the file, i don't know exactly what i am missing.

The error i get is the following:

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException thrown with message ""

Stacktrace:

## 20 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException

I got in my navigation the following:

```
{{ Menu::item('user-edit-profile','edit profile')}}
```

and in my routes file i got the following:

```
/*
*Edit profile's info (GET) 
*/
Route::get('/user/edit-profile',array( //en vez de /account/
        'as'    => 'user-edit-profile', //aquí también le cambio?
        'uses'  => 'ProfileController@getEditProfile' //en vez de AccountController
));
```

And in my ProfileController.php i got the following:

```
public function getEditProfile(){
    //all my stuff...
    return View::make('profile.edit',array('id_user'=>$id_user, 'nombre'=>$nombrepila));
    }
```

In my folder structure, inside views, i have this "profile" folder where i got my edit.blade.php file.

The problem is that i got this "not found exception error". What am i missing?

Comment: Does `{{ Menu::item('user-edit-profile','edit profile')}}` generate this exact URL or some HTML that has a link to this URL `/user/edit-profile`?

Comment: @Bogdan Yes, it does: /user/edit-profile

Comment: Try running `php composer dump-autoload` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Bogdan How do i do that? I have been searching, trying, and testing and can't get it to work :/

Comment: @Bogdan All right, i have found the error: /user/ always expects a variable, like /user/{NameOfUser}, so i changed the route to something else and now it is working ;) Thx anyway